# Transform error while trying to make a basic wordcloud

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I have installed matplotlib and wordcloud. When running the following code:

```
wordcloud1 = WordCloud().generate(just_message[0])
plt.show()
```

I receive this error message:

```
ValueError: 'transform' must be an instance of 'matplotlib.transform.Transform'
```

I have no idea what the error message means. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly.